# How do I seamlessly share a window from Mac OS X El Capitan to Windows 10?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, remote-control

Is there a way for me (as not an enterprise) to seamlessly share/remote access one window on my Mac from my Windows PC? I know Citrix has a version of this, but I'm not able to get their enterprise software.

Edit:
What I want to do is having remote access from a Windows machine on the same network as the Mac machine. But the remote access shouldn't be just a full screen remote as VNC or TeamViewer. I want to share/remote into just one application which I have on my Mac.

Comment: You can enable screen sharing on your Mac, which can be accessed with a VNC client from the PC.

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'seamlessly share/remote access on window on my Mac' would benefit from some clarification about specific user scenario (is somebody at remote machine etc).

There is professional grade TeamViewer which is [free for personal use](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/info/free-for-personal-use/) which includes option to share whole screen or specific application window.

There is possibility to use Microsoft Teams to share from [chat](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-your-screen-in-a-chat-in-teams-2de1c624-7fbe-4b0a-99f2-33385e7d3f18) or [meeting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-your-screen-during-a-meeting-90c84e5a-b6fe-4ed4-9687-5923d230d3a7) desktop, window or file.

Comment: Okay. Edited the question. I'll look into TeamViewer as well though. Thank you!